# How to strip one folder during Ant copy

Tags: ant

I have a file which has filepaths like "LibraryX/A/Stuff/FileY.txt", which I'm using as includesfile in Ant build. However, I'm in need of removing the "LibraryX/A/" part of the path DURING the copy process: The file gets copied from "LibraryX/A/Stuff/FileY.txt" and lands into "Stuff/FileY.txt". I've looked into few regexpmappers but haven't had any success with them at all. :/

The purpose for this is that the target folder can have custom files in "Stuff/MoreStuff" overwritten, and I want to use the overwrite="false" to keep the disk access into minimum and keeping the custom files intact.

Ant:

```
<copy todir="C:/targetdir/" overwrite="false">
    <fileset dir="C:/sourcedir/">
        <includesfile name="C:/targetdir/includes.file" />
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

Includes.file:

```
LibraryX/A/Stuff/FileA.txt
LibraryX/A/Stuff/FileB.txt
LibraryX/A/Stuff/FileC.txt
LibraryX/A/Stuff/FileY.txt
```

Sourcedir:

```
sourcedir/LibraryX/A/Stuff/FileA.txt
sourcedir/LibraryX/A/Stuff/FileB.txt
sourcedir/LibraryX/A/Stuff/FileC.txt
sourcedir/LibraryX/A/Stuff/FileY.txt
```

Target dir:

```
targetdir/Stuff/FileY.txt
```

Now, all the files in *Stuff* -folder at *sourcedir*, should end into the *Stuff* -folder in *targetdir*. But how?

**Bonus:** If I move the files from "targetdir/LibraryX/A/Stuff", they will overwrite everything in the "targetdir/Stuff" folder, even with the overwrite="false". Presumably because they are newer files than the ones in the Stuff folder currently.

**Note:** I could, of course, move the custom files away from the target directory, copy the stuff over and then move the custom files back, overwriting the new ones. But this accesses the disk quite a lot, slowing down the process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting with Ant v1.8.2 you can use the `cutdirsmapper` to strip some number of leading directories from file paths. See the very bottom of the [mapper type docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html).

```
<copy todir="C:/targetdir/" overwrite="false">
    <fileset dir="C:/sourcedir/">
        <includesfile name="C:/targetdir/includes.file" />
    </fileset>
    <cutdirsmapper dirs="2"/>
</copy>
```

**Bonus:** You could use the [touch](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/touch.html) ant task to make all the files in targetdir newer than all the source files and therefore prevent them from being overwritten.

Comment: This pretty much summed what I needed: cutdirsmapper does exactly the thing and I can use touch for older Ant versions. Thank you!

Comment: i am using ANT v1.8.2 eventhough i m getting the error like
`copy doesn't support the nested "cutdirsmapper" element`
Pls help me out

Answer (score 0):

In case you would like to remove something from the middle of path, during copy, you can use [filtermapper that is described here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html).

```
<copy todir="C:/targetdir/" overwrite="false">
    <fileset dir="C:/sourcedir/" includes="**/*.*" />
    <filtermapper>
      <replacestring from="LibraryX/A/" to="" />
    </filtermapper>
</copy>
```