# Execute ant task over sons of parent folder

Tags: ant

I was trying to execute a task over a fileset defined using something like this:

```
<target name="copyToTarget">
    <copy todir="${target.folder}/" >
        <fileset dir="../**/folder" />
    </copy>
</target>
```

Is there anyway to achieve this?

EDIT:

I saw by myself I can use something like:

```
<fileset dir="../" includes="*/folder/** />
```

but the problem is that this copies the whole structure since the parent folder and I only need it contents (e.g., with this I obtain

```
/target/son1/folder/contents
```

and I'm looking for

```
/target/contents
```

EDIT 2:

Using [How to strip one folder during Ant copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820375/how-to-strip-one-folder-during-ant-copy?rq=1) I managed how to get the result I need:

```
<target name="copyFolderToTarget">
    <copy todir="${target.folder}" >
        <fileset dir="../" includes="*/src_folder/**" />
        <cutdirsmapper dirs="2"/>
    </copy>
</target>
```

Comment: You should post your "edit 2" as an answer, and mark it as accepted.

Comment: This is a new account, I have to wait 5 hours 'till I can answer my own question XD